# NIO SocketChannel потеря соединения по истечений определенного времени

Tags: java, сокет

Привет всем, прошу прощения за за большое количество плохо написанного кода
Программа для трансляции звука по сети столкнулся с проблемой, что через 2-3 часа нормальной работы просто рвётся соединение с вылетом:

```
java.io.IOException: Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала 
установленное подключение
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
```

Просто может я что-то делаю не так как надо , В общем прошу помощи.

Код:

```
public class MainClass {

public static int SIZE = 8192;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connector f = new Connector();
    f.start();

    // Server
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                while (true) {

                    int num = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[4500];

                    AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Music.wav"));

                    AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0f, 16, 2, 4,
                            44100.0f, true);
                    AudioInputStream din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
                    SourceDataLine Output = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    Output.open(decodedFormat);

                    Output.start();

                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);

                    while (num != -1) {

                        Output.write(data, 0, num);

                        num = din.read(data);

                        buf.clear();
                        buf.put(createDataPack(new SomeSerilzeble(data, "Test")));
                        buf.flip();

                        for (Connection con : Connector.СlientsConnections) {

                            try {

                                con.channel.write(buf);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        Thread.sleep(15);

                    }

                    in.close();
                    din.close();
                    Output.drain();
                    Output.close();
                    buf.clear();

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }.start();

    // Client
    new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            try {

                SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
                socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1337));

                while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);

                AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0f, 16, 2, 4,
                        44100.0f, true);
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
                SourceDataLine Output = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                Output.open(decodedFormat);

                Output.start();

                while (true) {

                    try {
                        socketChannel.read(buf);

                        if (buf.remaining() == 0) {
                            SomeSerilzeble tse = (SomeSerilzeble) convertFromBytes(buf.array());
                            Output.write(tse.data, 0, tse.data.length);
                            buf.clear();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.start();

}

public static byte[] createDataPack(SomeSerilzeble obj) throws IOException {

    byte[] datapack = new byte[SIZE];

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(obj);
    byte[] somerealdata = bos.toByteArray();

    bos.close();
    out.close();

    int leghit = somerealdata.length;
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(leghit).array();

    datapack[0] = bytes[0];
    datapack[1] = bytes[1];
    datapack[2] = bytes[2];
    datapack[3] = bytes[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < somerealdata.length; i++) {
        datapack[4 + i] = somerealdata[i];
    }

    System.out.println(leghit + " Send ");
    somerealdata = null;
    bytes = null;

    return datapack;
}

public static Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    int leght = bytes[0] << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);

    System.out.println(leght + " acc ");

    try {
        byte[] rawdata = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 4, leght + 4);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawdata);
        ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        return in.readObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return leght;
 }

}
```

Connector:

```
public class Connector extends Thread {
public static volatile CopyOnWriteArrayList<Connection> СlientsConnections = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Connection>();

public void run() {

    try {

        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1337));

        while (true) {
            new Connection(serverSocketChannel.accept());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

}
```

Connection:

```
public class Connection {

public SocketChannel channel;

public Connection(SocketChannel sc) {

    channel = sc;

    try {
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        Connector.СlientsConnections.add(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

SomeSerilzeble:

```
public class SomeSerilzeble          
implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
byte[] data;
String mess;

public SomeSerilzeble(byte[] d, String g) {
    data = d;
    mess = g;

}

}
```